# Android parameterized sql query not working

Tags: android, sqlite

If I hardcode a number into the where section I get the rows I'm expecting back

```
Cursor cursor = db.query( tableName, 
new String[] {colID, colString, colNumber },  
colNumber + "=14", 
null, 
null, null, null, null);
```

If I instead put the number in as a parameter, I don't get any rows back.

```
Cursor cursor = db.query( tableName, 
new String[] {colID, colString, colNumber },  
colNumber + "=?", 
new String[] { String.valueOf(14) }, 
null, null, null, null);
```

What am I doing wrong in the second case?

Create table statements:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "
        + otherTableName + " ("
        + otherTableID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + otherTableString + " TEXT"
        + ");");

db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "
        + tableName + " ("
        + colID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + colString + " TEXT, "
        + colNumber + " REFERENCES "
        + otherTableName + "(" + otherTableID
            + "));");
```

Comment: Odd. Normally SQLite doesn't care about data types, but how did you define `colNumber`?

Comment: `colNumber` references an ID in a second table.

Comment: Please show your `"CREATE TABLE"` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that problem is your second DML statement, more accurate your declaration of foreign key. I think that it should be:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "
        + tableName + " ("
        + colID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + colString + " TEXT, "
        + colNumber + " INTEGER, "
        + " FOREIGN KEY (" + colNumber + ") REFERENCES "
        + otherTableName + "(" + otherTableID
            + "));");
```

I cannot explain myself other reason why it's not working. Your statements are equal except one uses hardcored value and second placeholder. Probably you tried parametrized statement on tableName table where i think you declared FK incorrectly and this was reason why you got any rows.

Placeholders work based on [SQLite's type affinity](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity)

If you defined column as `TEXT`, placeholder is replaced and value is compared as `col = 'value'`. If you defined column as `INTEGER`, placeholder is replaced and value is compared as `col = value`. But in your second DML statement, you didn't specified column's datatype, only that it references to some column somewhere.

Comment: Actually, parameters are *always* replaced as `col = 'value'` (i.e., as strings; this is a silly restriction in Android's DB interface), but SQLite's [type affinity](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity) will then compare it correctly for numeric-typed columns.

Comment: @CL. thanks for correction. Good to know. i was wrong with that.